# Non-Causal Autoregressive Time Series

Tags: statistics, time-series

The autoregressive process
$\phi(B)X_t = Z_t$ is called *causal* if the autoregressive characteristic function $1 - \phi_1z - \cdot \cdot \cdot - \phi_pz ^ {p}$ has no zeroes inside of the unit circle, and it is called purely *non-causal* if all the zeros of the characteristic function are inside of the unit circle. The *causal* autoregressive model depends on past and present values of $Z_t$ and the *non-causal* autoregressive model depends on future values of $Z_t$.

I tried to simulate *non-causal* $AR(1)$ and $AR(2)$ and perceived that the plots were completely different from the regular time series plot. How could these models be used for real data? Basically, are these models appropriate to use for such a purpose? This is my first question and I am not sure if I am asking this question correctly, so please let me know if I need to clarify anything.
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: This is probably better suited on CrossValidated, but observationally there is a casual model that gives the same observation as a noncausal one.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was particularly interested in your point about how there can be a causal model that gives the same observation as a non-causal one and I hope to learn more about this topic. I appreciate your help.